# How can I know the master branch name of a repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I assume that the name `master` branch which is the "main" branch that everyone is working in a git repository,is just a convention. Right?
So how can I know what is the "main" branch name in a git repository that has overriden so as not to use the name `master`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `master` is just a convention. Not every repository has a branch called `master`. Also git allows you arbitrary work flows. Different projects use different branching strategies. There might be something like a "main branch", but sometimes there is simply no need for it.

You can always use `git branch -m` to give a commit a new name and `git reset` to give a name a new commit.

Most of the time you can use the name of the branch to get an idea what it includes. Otherwise can use something like `gitk` to have a look at your commit graph. This might help you to recognize something like a "main branch".

Comment: `git log --decorate --graph --oneline` gives a fairly usable text-only approximation of the gitk graph visualization.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you've already cloned the repository and the name of the remote is `origin`, then you can run the following:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

This will usually print `refs/remotes/origin/main` or `refs/remotes/origin/master`, but if the project chose `someotherbranch` as their default it'll show `refs/remotes/origin/someotherbranch`.

Some background:  In a local (non-bare) repository, `HEAD` indicates what is currently checked out.  In a shared (bare) repository, there is no working directory so there is nothing checked out.  Thus, in bare repositories, `HEAD` is used to indicate the default branch for the repository (the branch you get when you run `git clone <url>`).  When you clone a repository, the remote repository's `HEAD` reference is copied to your local `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` reference.

##### Caveats

- If the remote `HEAD` reference does not point to a valid commit (for example, you are cloning a newly created empty repo), `git clone` will not create `origin/HEAD`.
- `git remote update` and `git fetch` do not update `origin/HEAD` to match the current value of the remote `HEAD` reference.  (You can run `git remote set-head origin -a` to update or create `origin/HEAD`, assuming the remote repository's `HEAD` points to a valid commit.)

I would argue that both of these behaviors are bugs.  However, I believe older versions of Git (circa 2013) updated `origin/HEAD` to match the remote, which would mean that the Git devs intentionally changed the behavior.  If that is correct, presumably there was a good reason for the change.

Comment: Won't this print the current `HEAD`? Couldn't the `HEAD` be in *any* branch?

Comment: @Cratylus:  That command prints the value of `origin/HEAD`, not `HEAD` (note that `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a different reference from `HEAD`).  Yes, someone could change the name of the remote repository's default branch at any time, but it's very rare.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I just get `fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref` (on `git version 2.36.2`). Tried on multiple different repository clones.

Comment: @akaihola I updated the answer with some caveats.

Comment: In versions of git where this no longer works, it looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056710/2071807) will do the job.

Comment: This no longer works in git 2.41.0 (probably earlier) even taking into account the above caveats.